# Can't upgrade to 16.04 / autoremove having issues

Tags: command-line, upgrade

Alright, so for a while now, 15.10 has kept me from updating. It would say there is too much things in my boot folder, so I would use sudo apt-get autoremove in the terminal to get rid of them. Today, when I tried to upgrade, and enter the command in question, this is what I got in my terminal.

```
tao@tao-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up postfix (2.11.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Adding group `postfix' (GID 134) ...
groupadd: existing lock file /etc/gshadow.lock without a PID
groupadd: cannot lock /etc/gshadow; try again later.
addgroup: `/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 134 postfix' returned error code 10. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
tao@tao-ubuntu:~$
```

Anyone else got an idea?

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` then run the `autoremove` again?

Comment: I inputted the commands as you said: Will results in comments.

Comment: tao@tao-ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for tao: 
Setting up postfix (2.11.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Adding group `postfix' (GID 134) ...
groupadd: existing lock file /etc/gshadow.lock without a PID
groupadd: cannot lock /etc/gshadow; try again later.
addgroup: `/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 134 postfix' returned error code 10. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix

Comment: tao@tao-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

Comment: Setting up postfix (2.11.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Adding group `postfix' (GID 134) ...
groupadd: existing lock file /etc/gshadow.lock without a PID
groupadd: cannot lock /etc/gshadow; try again later.
addgroup: `/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 134 postfix' returned error code 10. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: I went back to the software updater and it said that the installation or removal of a software update failed.

Comment: Thank you.  You could add this to your question.  It does look like `postfix` needs to be removed from the system.  If you were using it for something, it will have to be added back.  `sudo apt-get purge postfix`  I was having a similar issue with `fail2ban` and purging it actually worked for me.

Comment: Ran the software updater again after purging postfix and it didn't work, saying that it failed to download repository information. I ran 'sudo apt-get update' in the terminal and got this:

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: You will have to find where those are at and have them commented out.  They could either be in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or they are actual files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder.  Those are for wily.  You would need to see if they have ones for Xenial.

Comment: I went into the settings and just unchecked the box as opposed to going into the file. Now everything's working okay. Thanks for your help Terrence! I'm fairly new to this site, is there I way I can increase  your reputation or commend you formally on this site?

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Through our chat here, we found that you have a repository that is not compatible with `Xenial 16.04`.  The actual [repository](https://launchpad.net/~kilian/+archive/ubuntu/f.lux) shows that it stopped distros after `14.04`.

```
W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/… 404 Not Found 
W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/… 404 Not Found 
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The repositories that are giving you errors need to be disabled or removed from your system.  The `kilian/f.lux` repositories need to be disabled.

The following locations are where the repositories are stored and can be disabled or removed from.

*Screenshot from my system that will probably not match yours*

**Software & Updates in the Other Sofware tab**

Unselect the repository that is giving you errors.

[image]

After the repository is unselected, re-run the `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get autoremove` to see if your problem has been fixed.

Hope this helps!